# playsinline not working for video on iOS vue js quasar and showing full screen mode by default

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, html5-video, quasar

I'm working on a app using quasar. It's working fine on all other browsers but giving the problem on IOS mode. When run it on IOS simulator, and tried to play the video it will automatically go to FullScreen Mode and I want to undo this.

I read a lot of answers here and all of them are suggesting to use **playsinline** but that's not working for me

[image: See I'm using playsinline to avoid full screen but it's not working and whenever I play the video it will go to full screen mode. Even I tried to use autoplay, tried to play the video manually. In both cases it is going in full screen mode]

See I'm using playsinline to avoid full screen but it's not working and whenever I play the video it will go to full screen mode. Even I tried to use autoplay, tried to play the video manually. In both cases it is going in full screen mode.

Has anybody seen this before? Is there a way to fix? If not, is there a way to detect a video going full screen and abort it?

Answer (score 0):

[`playsinline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) requests a playback **preferred** in non-fullscreen. This does not imply that the video will always be played in non-fullscreen. As Safari on iOS does not support the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) fully you need a workaround.

Try to set [`preferFullWindow=true`](https://videojs.com/guides/options/#preferfullwindow) this will fill the browser window instead of making it fullscreen. This should work for you as it does not use the Fullscreen API.